# Automated Test With Image Comparison

Tags: c#, automated-tests

I have a WPF application and I have a custom object (the output) with images and text. I need to check if the output has a correct format. I tried with Coded UI but, because the element is a custom object, I can't compare its properties.

Which is the best tool to compare visual objects? I also need it to be able to automate the test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following free solutions:

1. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38619/Finding-a-Bitmap-contained-inside-another-Bitmap)  - for compare images.
2. [Tesseract](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) - for recognition text on an image.
3. [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) - just nice framework for work with images.